# How to release:perform with git-crypted files

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin, exec-maven-plugin, git-crypt

I used **git-crypt** (https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt) to encrypt a property file containing sensitive data (passwords etc.) in my **Java Maven project**.

Preparing of the release run without problems.
But the execution of **"mvn release:perform" failed** because this operation do an automated:

- checkout release tag from SCM
- build and deploy released code

The problem is, that my property file is **checked out encrypted** and so the execution of some integration test failed.

**It should be possible somehow to decrypt my file automatically during the release:perform process.**

I need a solution kind of this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>cmd</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>/c</argument>
                    <argument>git-crypt unlock my-unlock-keyfile</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <completionGoals>exec:exec</completionGoals>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But sadly this code works only for preparing releases.

Comment: Just run `mvn exec:exec release:perform`?

Comment: "mvn exec:exec release:perform" is not doing what I want, because I need the unlock done DURING the release:perform and not before. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Why do you need to do it before?

Comment: I don't know about git-crypt, but you can change the goals that are run during `perform` and `prepare`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution now:

```
<build>
    <plugins>   
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>cmd</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>/c</argument>
                    <argument>git-crypt unlock path\to\my-unlock-keyfile</argument>
                </arguments>
                <successCodes>
                    <successCode>0</successCode>
                    <successCode>1</successCode> <!-- while release preparation exit code 1 it thrown because of unsaved changes; this is only a workaround; -->
                </successCodes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```